# How to link Javascript to a dynamic website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having trouble linking a javascript file to a dynamic website i made through php. My file structure is simply just:

> **index**.php, **css** folder (which is working correctly), **jscript** folder (does
>   not work) and a **pages** folder (has all my pages)

My pages are simple just

> **header**.php, **registrationContent**.php and **footer**.php

My index just includes all 3 php and it works perfectly fine. My problem is no matter what I do, whether inline, or soft coded javascripting it does not work. I am certain my syntax in the javascript is fine, its just the linking.

My header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Safe Drive Website</title>
        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/regStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jscript/javascripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topBar" id="topBar"><a href=""><input type="Submit" value="Contact Us" class="topNavButton"/></a></div>
        <div id="bannerText"><h1 class="mainHeader">SafeDrive</h1><h2 class="subHeader">Developer's Tool</h2></div>
```

I close the tags in the footer.php

Comment: Where is your code? Can't really help without it!

Comment: so your problem is that your path to oyur .js file is pointing nothing  ?

Comment: before we go any further: you know PHP is serverside, and JS is clientside, and that you need to have html `<script src=".."></scripts>` tags in your HTML so that the browser (not php) loads that JS, right?

Comment: please add the `<head>` tag of your code

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are included directly in your html page.
use the following line in your html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/javascript/file.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I already know that part. It is just that it won't link.. I am thinking that dynamic websites have a different way of linking jscripts..

Comment: No they don't. What happens on the serverside is unknown to the client that parses the HTML, and that's the location where your problem seems to be.

Comment: I don't get it then. My jscript folder is in the same place as the index.php and it wont link at all..

Comment: Let's do a simple test, put your javascript on the same folder as your  index.php file, then call your js file simply. Check the name too, it happens quite often to make a mistake when typing the name.

By the way, make a syntax mistake in it and check in your developer console if you see that error happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably uncommon, but I thought of answering my own question because I found a solution, so that anyone else having the same problem could try mine.

Basically, it was loaded, the only problem was that the javascript functions weren't loaded and so to do that, i had to add:

```
window.onload = myJscriptFunction();
```

on any tag (body, footer etc. refer to w3schools for that information)

I do hope this helps anyone facing the same problem ^_^